Counting Logically Distinct Expressions Involving Quantifiers and Variables

Problem

For an integer $n \geq 0$, Literal Lily will write an expression on the board that is $2n$ symbols long. It starts with a $\forall$ or $\exists$ symbol, then one of the $n$ variables $V_1, \dots, V_n$, then a $\vee$ or $\wedge$ symbol, then a different one of those variables, etc. By the end, she will have written each variable exactly once. She will now append $P(V_1, \dots, V_n)$ to the end of the expression, representing a formula in the $n$ variables. Let there be $f(n)$ logically different statements that Literal Lily can write. Find the minimal degree of a polynomial interpolating the points
$$(0, f(0)), (1, f(1)), (2, f(2)), \dots, (n - 1, f(n - 1)), \left(n, \frac{f(n)}{2}\right)$$
Note that $f(0) = 1$. Two statements are logically different if there is some predicate $P$ that makes one true and one false.

background

I came across this problem on AoPS, but the original post has since been deleted. I found the problem interesting and wanted to share it here.

Some thoughts

However, I have some thoughts on how to interpret the problem:

Does the initial string of length $2n$ consist only of quantifiers and variables, or can it also include logical connectives? For instance, $\forall V_1 \exists V_2 P(V_1, V_2)$  makes sense, whereas $\forall V_1 \wedge V_2 P(V_1, V_2)$ seems unclear.

Is $f(n)$ the number of different initial strings of length $2n$, or does it refer to the entire expression, including the predicate $P$? Additionally, what are the possible predicates$P$, and how are they quantified over the variables $V_1, \dots, V_n$?

If we assume the initial string consists only of quantifiers, the logical equivalence might depend only on the order of the quantifiers and the location of each variable within contiguous blocks of identical quantifiers.


I hypothesize that  $f(n)$ could be represented as:
$$
f(n) = 2\sum \frac{n!}{k_1! \cdots k_m!}
$$
where the sum is over the tuples $(k_1, \dots, k_m)$ with $k_i > 0$ and $k_1 + k_2 + \cdots + k_m = n$. The factor of two accounts for the fact that a formula can start with either an existential or a universal quantifier, with the blocks alternating.
Any thoughts or further clarification on this approach would be greatly appreciated!
I'm not sure if this will be useful to anyone, but if I recall correctly, someone suggested a hint: inductively construct these polynomials by adding loops. A closed form for $f(n)$ isn't necessary.
